# visual studio refactoring / renaming does not update Name property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, windows-forms-designer

Visual Studio 2010.

In the form designer .cs file:

Before refactor / rename:

```
        // TextBox1
        this.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1";
```

After refactor / rename:

```
        // TextBox1
       this.MyTextBox.Name = "TextBox1";
```

After some time (which includes Run, Quit, Edit the form...):

```
        // MyTextBox
       this.MyTextBox.Name = "MyTextBox";
```

How can I force Visual Studio to update the Name property right away?

Comment: If you want to change the property name, then do it in the property editor. *.designer.cs is not intended for manual editing.

Comment: @bansi > tried a rebuild? --- yes. that doesn't do it.

Comment: @Roman Ko > If you want to change the property name -- Sure, I could change all the properties, one by one, manually. But that's not my question. My question is how to get VS to change the Name property as well as the object's name.   > designer.cs is not intended for manual editing --- I am not editing it; I am just opening it to show you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Refactor > Rename`, make sure the `Search in strings` checkbox is set.

[image]